# Android studio open opencv file issue

Tags: android, opencv

May i know how to open the opencv file by using android studio. After i imported the file , i found that all the java file in opencv was unexecutable, any solution can convert the java file to be able to use on android studio??

Comment: Sorry i am new in android studio, please help me :(

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not link external sources, when it comes to code or something similar. The external source could go down and the whole question would be broken. Further more try to extract only the important code pieces that are important for´your question.

Comment: Thanks jannik for correcting me, i deleted the external sources and i just want to show that the file is unexecutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are importing external text file, then you have to import that file... Go to Android Studio Project> Right Click on 'main' to add Folder >  res Folder,Assets folder, etc will be there... Create folder as per your requirement and add your opencv file to it....

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, do you have the teamviewer?